# Get UnirestConfigException when using Unirest API in Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, unirest

Getting Unirest Config exception when I use java with Unirest API to call the web service asynchronous way. It is working as expected in the sync method.

I am writing a Java code for Apache Spark to call REST API.

Future> future = ui.post("http://x.x.x.x:x/xwa/evalrules").body(Str).asStringAsync(
                            new Callback() {

```
                            public void failed(UnirestException e) {
                               System.out.println("JTX Failed Get message"+ e.getMessage());

                            }

                            public void completed(HttpResponse<String> resp) {
                                System.out.println(new Date() + " Consumer JTXX recvd response  -> " + resp.getStatus() + "/" + resp.getBody());
                                //out_JSON=resp.body();
                            }

                            public void cancelled() {
                                System.out.println("The request has been cancelled JTX");
                            }

                        });
```

Expected: It is working as expected for first few calls. post that it is failing. I suspected the timeout so i have already disabled using approach.

Config c = Unirest.config().socketTimeout(0).connectTimeout(0).concurrency(10, 8);
UnirestInstance ui = new UnirestInstance(c);

Error Message:

kong.unirest.UnirestConfigException: Http Clients are already built in order to build a new config execute Unirest.config().reset() before changing settings. 
This should be done rarely.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this will be highly appreciated. Thanks. 
Muthu